# Android ListView with header Setting empty view will cause the header to be hidden

Tags: android, listview

Currently I have this listView with a header.

```
View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.headerview, null);
View emptyView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.emptyView, null);
mlistView.addHeaderView(headerView);
mListView.setEmptyView(emptyView);
```

this is my emptyView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/empty_layout_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/empty_textview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="No items"
        android:textSize="24dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Header Xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullname"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


    </LinearLayout>
```

Note I put the emptyView in a seperate XML since I'm changing its color. Currently I can't proceed since setting the empty view shows only a white layout without the header even the text "No items". so i guess its not working. Am I missing Something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The view must be added to your activity's layout:

```
final int mp = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
addContentView(emptyView, new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(mp, mp));
```

The `ListView` only sets the visiblity of the `EmptyView` if one is present. In your case the visibility is set but since it's not added, it won't show.

Comment: this one fixed the problem for the layout is shown as pure white. but the problem is that the header is not showing

Comment: @Michael post `headerview.xml`.

Comment: @Michael add some text to the `TextView`.

Comment: why? I set the values during onCreate

Comment: @Michael trying doesn't hurt, and in this case helps.

Comment: Already put a text but still the emptyView eats all the layout

Comment: @Michael if the `ListView` is empty, the header won't be displayed.

Comment: yup. that's my problem. How do i fix that? if that how listview works then i think its wrong to hide the header also

Comment: @Michael that's how ListView works and it's not wrong IMO. You should add the header's layout to the emptyView's layout if you want different results.

Comment: damn. this android thing is depressing. By the way thanks for the help. I think I'll just set the listView height to wrap content and a hidden empty view below it. so when the list size = 0 ill just show the empty view.

Comment: @Michael no need to set your ListView's height to wrap content. Also don't imitate the emptyView yourself, i.e. when you add it to your activity's layout (xml or programmatically) just call `setEmptyView(findViewById(R.id.empty))` and you'll be done.